# Are these partial order or total orders?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, order-theory

I just want to know if the following are considered partially ordered sets or total set.

Here is the definition:

1. $\mathbb{R}^2$ : (a,b) *R* (c,d) iff $a\leqslant c$ **and** $b\leqslant d$
2. $\mathbb{R}^2$ : (a,b) *R* (c,d) iff $a\leqslant c$ **or** $b\leqslant d$

I believe that the number 1 is a partial ordered set and not a total set because it is not comparable. For example, (a,b) = (0,1) and (c,d) = (1,0) simply wouldn't work out.

Comment: You believe the right thing.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't the same apply to 2?

Answer (score 2):

The second isn't even an order, since an order has to be antisymmetric...i.e if $xRy$ and $yRx$, then $x=y$ for any order.   In the case of 2, you have $(0,1)R(1,0)$ and $(1,0)R(0,1)$ but $(1,0)\ne (0,1)$

Comment: The right term for it is *antisymmetric*. A relation is antisymmetric if $xRy\wedge yRx$ implies that $x=y$. A relation is asymmetric if $xRy\Rightarrow\neg yRx$

Comment: Editted to fix, thanks